# How to handle independent variable in regression where no relationship exists between samples

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-logit

I would like to use a multinomial logistic regression to get win probabilities for each of the 5 horses that participate in any given race using each horses previous average speed.

```
RACE_ID    H1_SPEED     H2_SPEED    H3_SPEED    H4_SPEED    H5_SPEED    WINNING_HORSE
1          40.482081    44.199627   42.034929   39.004813   43.830139   5
2          39.482081    42.199627   41.034929   41.004813   40.830139   4
```

I am stuck on how to handle the independent variables for each horse given that any of the 5 horses average speed can be placed in any of `H1_SPEED` through `H5_SPEED`.

Given the fact that for each race I can put any of the 5 horses under `H1_SPEED` meaning there is no real relationship between `H1_SPEED` from `RACE_ID 1` and `H1_SPEED` from `RACE_ID 2` other than the arbitrary position I selected.

Would there be any difference if the dataset looked like this -

- For `RACE_ID 1` I swapped `H3_SPEED` and `H5_SPEED` and changed `WINNING_HORSE` from `5` to `3`
- For `RACE_ID 2` I swapped `H4_SPEED` and `H1_SPEED` and changed `WINNING_HORSE` from `4` to `1`

```
RACE_ID    H1_SPEED     H2_SPEED    H3_SPEED    H4_SPEED    H5_SPEED    WINNING_HORSE
1          40.482081    44.199627   43.830139   39.004813   42.034929   3
2          41.004813    42.199627   41.034929   39.482081   40.830139   1
```

Is this an issue, if so how should this be handled? What if I wanted to add more independent features per horse?

Comment: Is the problem that, for example in  `RACE_ID` #1, that the value for `H5_SPEED` is could be the value for any of the 5 horses and is not linked specifically to the winning horse (i.e., horse #5)?  Or is it that across races, the number for the horses change.  That is, a hypothetical horse named "Foobar" could be horse #5 in `RACE_ID` #1 and also horse #4 in `RACE_ID` #2?  Hence, the same horse is re-labeled across races.

Comment: The latter, "Foobar" could be horse #5 in `RACE_ID` #1 and another hypothetical horse "Barfoo" could be horse#5 in `RACE_ID` #2. "Foobar" could also be horse #4 in `RACE_ID` #2 as you mentioned @jluchman

Comment: Another question is if "Foobar" won `RACE_ID #1` I could have put "Foobar"'s speed as `H3_SPEED` and changed `WINNING_HORSE` to `3` the numbering is arbitrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not possible to link the arbitrary horse numbering by race to a literal horse through some lookup table (which it sounds like it is not), it will not be possible to get meaningful probabilities for the horse numbers as they do not refer to the same horse across races.

It sounds like, across races, there may be multiple features for each horse other than speed.  If these 5 horse numbers always refer to the same literal horses (with arbitrary labels), and there are multiple features per race, it may be worthwhile to attempt to use those all the features to match the arbitrary horse labels to across races to harmonize labels for a literal horse.

The idea would then be for each race to attempt to match the horse labels based on the values of all the features.  An approach like this would make the strong assumption that the horses have a similar profile across races in terms of the values collected on each horse in each race.  That said, it may be the only way to get the data in shape for subsequent modeling.

In effect, what I'm recommending is a kind of fuzzy matching/data linking approach (see probabilistic data linking section at the wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage)).

Regarding the second question, changing the labels should not matter given they are (currently) arbitrary. Again, the important thing to do to make the probability estimates meaningful is to harmonize the literal horse to horse number mapping across races.

Comment: Would a conditional logit be better suited for this problem (https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c6.pdf) using something like pylogit in python or mlogit in R which allows me to use features that are attributes of the choice alternatives (the horses)

Comment: "If it is not possible to link the arbitrary horse numbering by race to a literal horse through some lookup table" Also for this it is possible as I have an id for each horse, but I am unsure on how to do the linking